# Operator overloading, operator= in class that "Does not name a type"

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
class GridElem {
public:
    GridElem();
    ~GridElem();
    GirdElem &operator=(const char _idata);
    friend char operator-(const GridElem &lhs, const char rhs);
private:
    char _data;
};

inline char operator-(const GridElem &lhs, const char rhs) {
    return lhs._data - rhs;
}
```

I don't understand, I've implemented it in `GridElem.cpp`

```
GirdElem& GridElem::operator=(const char _idata) {
    _data = _idata;
    return *this;
}
```

Is something elese wrong with my config or can you spot the error please?

Comment: Is the class definition accessible at the point where you define the operator?

Comment: Did you include `GridElem.h` in `GridElem.cpp` ?

Comment: The error is a typo, `GirdElem`, that @Baptiste Wicht immediately pointed out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have written GirdElem instead of GridElem in the return type